Cant get ag-grid row to expand a specific row
I can't get ag-grid row to expand.
export const alwaysShownColumns = [
    {
        width: 52,
        maxWidth: 52,
        filter: null,
        showDisabledCheckboxes: true,
        pinned: 'left',
        headerClass: 'no-highlight checkboxHeader',
        cellStyle: { padding: '0px 12px 0px 24px' },
        sortable: false,
        lockPosition: true,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        cellRenderer: 'checkboxCellRenderer',
    },
    {
        field: 'type',
        width: 76,
        maxWidth: 76,
        cellStyle: { padding: '0 24px' },
        headerClass: 'walkme-table-header',
        pinned: 'left',
        cellRenderer: 'typeCellRenderer',
        headerComponentParams: { alwaysShowFilter: true },
        lockPosition: true,
        suppressSizeToFit: true,
        filterParams: {
            suppressMiniFilter: true,
            cellRenderer: 'typeFilterItemRenderer',
            values: Object.keys(DeployableType).filter((key) => DeployableType[key] !== DeployableType.Folder),
        },
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        filter: null,
        pinned: 'left',
        minWidth: 220,
        width: 220,
        cellRenderer: 'nameCellRenderer',
        cellClass: 'noPaddingCell',
        lockPosition: true,
        flex: 2,
        comparator: caseInsensitiveStringComparator,
    },
];

export const defaultEnvStatusColumns: ColDef[] = [
    {
        field: 'publishStatusByEnv.0',
        headerName: 'Status on Production',
        ...publishStatusColParams,
    },
    {
        field: 'publishStatusByEnv.3',
        headerName: 'Status on Test',
        ...publishStatusColParams,
    },
];

export const workflowLabelColumnDef: ExportedColDef = {
    field: 'workflowLabel',
    headerName: 'Tagging',
    cellRenderer: 'businessDomainRenderer',
    cellClass: 'noPaddingCell',
    minWidth: 224,
    width: 224,
    flex: 1,
};

export const metadataColumns: ExportedColDef[] = [
    {
        field: 'itemId',
        headerName: 'Item ID',
        minWidth: 120,
        flex: 1,
        filter: null,
        sortable: false,
        suppressMenu: true,
        cellRenderer: 'itemIdCellRenderer',
    },
    {
        field: 'created',
        headerName: 'Creation date',
        minWidth: 180,
        flex: 1.5,
        sort: 'asc',
        comparator: createdDateComparator,
        ...dateColParams,
    },
    {
        field: 'autoPlay',
        headerName: 'Auto Play',
        comparator: autoPlayComparator,
        minWidth: 120,
        flex: 1,
    },
    {
        field: 'segments',
        headerName: 'Segments',
        cellRenderer: 'segmentsRenderer',
        exportValueFormatter: ({ value = [] }) => (value.length ? value.map(({ name }) => name).join(', ') : ''),
        minWidth: 232,
        sortable: false,
        flex: 2,
    },
    {
        field: 'createdBy',
        headerName: 'Created By',
        cellRenderer: 'createdByRenderer',
        cellClass: 'noPaddingCell',
        minWidth: 180,
        exportValueFormatter: ({ value }) => value?.name || '',
        comparator: createdByComparator,
        flex: 1.5,
    },
    {
        field: 'metadata.notes',
        headerName: 'Notes',
        cellRenderer: 'notesCellRenderer',
        cellClass: 'noPaddingCell',
        sortable: false,
        minWidth: 180,
        flex: 1.5,
    },
    {
        field: 'url',
        headerName: 'URL',
        cellRenderer: 'urlCellRenderer',
        minWidth: 180,
        flex: 1.5,
        comparator: caseInsensitiveStringComparator,
    },
];

export const actionsColumn = {
    filter: null,
    headerName: '',
    headerClass: 'no-highlight no-padding flex-end',
    sortable: false,
    width: 64,
    cellRenderer: 'actionsCellRenderer',
    pinned: 'right',
    suppressSizeToFit: true,
};

const gridRenderProps: AgGridReactProps = {
        ...gridConfig,
        masterDetail: true,
        className: 'my-content-root-grid',
        domLayout: 'normal',
        columnDefs: [...columnsDef, { field: 'test', headerName: 'test2k' }],
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
        rowData: deployables,
        suppressCellSelection: true,
        suppressRowClickSelection: true,
        suppressRowHoverHighlight: false,
        rowHeight: 48,
        headerHeight: 40,
        animateRows: true,
        immutableData: true,
        getRowNodeId: (data) => data.id,
        ...useGridDragHandlers(),
        onCellClicked(event) {
            if (
                DISABLED_PREVIEW_DRAWER_CELLS.includes(event.colDef.cellRenderer) ||
                !!itemIdToRename ||
                actionBarVisible ||
                isActionInProgress
            ) {
                return;
            }
            if (appFeatures.deployablesPreview) {
                dispatch(setOpenPreview({ deployable: _cloneDeep(event.data) }));
            }
        },
        async onRowSelected(event: RowSelectedEvent) {
            if (event.data.type !== DeployableType.Folder || event.node.data.disabled) return;

            const folderId = event.data.itemId;
            const isSelected = event.node['selected'];

            if (!hasSearchTerm) {
                if (isSelected) {
                    fillFlatCache([folderId]);
                } else {
                    emptyFolderFlatCache(folderId);
                }
                return;
            }

            const rowsToChangeSelectState = await flatCache[folderId].promise;

            gridRef.current?.api?.forEachNode((node) => {
                if (
                    rowsToChangeSelectState.find(
                        (row) => row.itemId === node.data.itemId && row.numericType === node.data.numericType
                    )
                ) {
                    node.setSelected(isSelected, undefined, true);
                    node.setData({ ...node.data, disabled: isSelected });
                }
            });
        },
        onGridReady(event: GridReadyEvent) {
            event.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        },
        onColumnVisible: () => gridRef.current?.api.sizeColumnsToFit(),
        onColumnMoved: updateColumnOrder,
    };

I'm trying to expand specific row - "type" and a specific type of the dataRow has children.
Lets say that my data is like this: [{a},{b, childrenOfB},{c},{d},{e, childrenOfE}], so in my case b and e should be expandable rows.
As you can see in the example "Opportunity Mini Menu" is a specific type and it has children.
enter image description here
For some reason even the basic example from ag-grid is not working, what am I missing?
